# Error updating intel drivers

Tags: 14.04, intel-graphics

I am using the latest Intel Graphics Installer for Linux, trying to update my Ubuntu 14.04 laptop, but get the following error preventing me:

```
Error running transaction: GDBus.Error:org.debian.apt.TransactionFailed: error-dep-resolution-failed: The following packages have unmet dependencies:

i915-3.15-3.13-dkms: Depends: dkms but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: linux-headers but it is a virtual package
```

How can I fix this issue?